# manipulate array of hashes using javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Can you please show me the best way to process/ manipulate this array of hashes using javascript function chaining. I want to filter the data and return ONLY an array of hashes that contains data that in NOT all 0’s.

```
data = [
    {name: "apple", data: [0, 0, 0]},
    {name: "banana", data: [1, 0, 2]},
    {name: "carrot", data: [0, 0, 0]},
    {name: "pineapple", data: [0, 0, 3]},
]

//result after filtering

data = [
    {name: "banana", data: [1, 0, 2]},
    {name: "pineapple", data: [0, 0, 3]},
]
```

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
data.filter((hash,i) => {hash.data.every((elem,i)=> elem == 0);
```

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of 
data.filter((hash,i) => {hash.data.every((elem,i)=> elem == 0); return hash  } ) 
but this doesn’t work and I would like some guidance. Thank you again!

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in JavaScript code, use ASCII quotes.

Comment: Use `.filter` and use the `every` or `some` method in the filtering function.

Comment: Why does the third element have a `carrot` property instead of `data`? Is that supposed to be the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost right. You need to invert the result of the `every` test, since you want the elements that *aren't* all zero; you could also use `some` and test for non-zero. Also, don't put curly braces around the body of the function if you just want to return the result of the expression.

```js
data = [{
    name: "apple",
    data: [0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    data: [1, 0, 2]
  },
  {
    name: "carrot",
    data: [0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    name: "pineapple",
    data: [0, 0, 3]
  },
];
console.log(data.filter(hash => !hash.data.every(elem => elem == 0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
const data = [{name:”apple”,data:[0,0,0]}, {name:”banana”,data:[1,0,2]}, {name:””,carrot:[0,0,0]}, {name:”pineapple”,data:[0,0,3]}, ]

const nonzero = data.filter(({data}) => data.some(Boolean));
```